# Git Modified - Object not being added properly

Tags: git

I keep having this issue where it keeps showing modified: Aisis-Core:

```
nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)
adam@adam-VirtualBox:~/Dropbox/AisisGit/Aisis-Core$ git add -A
adam@adam-VirtualBox:~/Dropbox/AisisGit/Aisis-Core$ git status
# On branch tests
# Changes to be committed:
#   (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)
#
#   new file:   Aisis-Core
#   new file:   functions.php
#   new file:   index.php
#   new file:   style.css
#
# Changes not staged for commit:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
#   (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
#   (commit or discard the untracked or modified content in submodules)
#
#   modified:   Aisis-Core (modified content, untracked content)
```

If I do **git add -A** or **git add Aisis-Core** then do git status I still see **modified: Aisis-Core**

thoughts?

Comment: what does "ls -al ." show?  Aisis-Core looks like a file, but you say below it is a directory, or is this a link?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go look at the tutorial at the [git documentation page](http://git-scm.com/documentation). `git add` does just stage the changes, until you do a `git commit` they aren't really locked away in the repository.

Comment: even if I did a git commit -a -m "message" I will still see modified: Aisis-Core. after I do git status

Comment: `git commit -a` asks `git` to commit all files under version control that are modified in the working area. If you did `git add somefile` before, this looks like a bug. What version of `git` is this? What environment?

Comment: git version 1.7.10.4 in a ubuntu 12.10 inside virtual box. I tried git add Aisis-Core and then git commit -a -m "message" only to see after git status modified: Aisis-Core. Could this be because the folder git was initialized in is called Aisis-Core and the folder I am trying to add is Aisis-Core

Comment: Aisis-Core is a directory? It it perhaps empty? `git` does _not_ store empty directories in the repository.

Comment: Thats not what I mean and I know that. Aisis-Core is the parent directory, inside that is another directory called Aisis-Core could the parent and child directory be a issue? Git is initialized inside Aisis-Core (the parent) inside Aisis-Core is a child directory (Aisis-Core) inside that is a bunch of files. Look at the OP to see the parent and child

Comment: The name of the directory containing the git repository should be completely irrelevant... OK, I just did: `mkdir -p Aisis-Core/Aisis-Core; for i in a b c d; do echo $i > Aisis-Core/$i; done; cd Aisis-Core; git init; git add Aisis-Core; git commit -a -m message; git status`. This reports a clean working directory (as it should). Fedora 18, git-1.8.1.2.526.gf51a757 (self compiled). Something _this_ fundamental is _very_ unlikely to go wrong.

Comment: Perhaps you did `git init` both in the parent and in the child? Or copied a directory with `.git` in it around? Something like that might get `git` confused.